# JPA - Hibernate session is closed, but entitymanager works

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-session

Given the two line of code :

```
entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, myId);

((Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate()).load(MyEntity.class, myId);
```

The first instruction works fine, but the second one throws org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!. Any idea ?

Context : spring batch 3.0.6 / hibernate 3.5.0

Info : EntityManager is injected :

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

**Update 1**

I can see in the find method a call to this.getSession() that open a new session if the session is null(in EntityManagerImpl.getRawSession)

**Update 2**

In the second situation the getSession method is not call but a class called SharedEntityManagerCreator that close the session :

```
if(isNewEm) {
  EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(target1);
}
```

Comment: Are u calling the above two lines in the same flow one by one? What happens if you swap them?

Comment: My aim is to use the hibernate session only because I need the scroll method of the Query class. So this is a simple test. I run each instruction in a different test case.

Answer (score 1):

With proper JPA transaction management the underlying Hibernate `Session` should already be open. Make sure you annotate your service method with `@Transactional` if you're using declarative transaction management (the underlying transaction manager should be JPA aware). Should you not use declarative transaction management, you could call

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

Don't forget to close the transaction with `commit()` or `rollback()` when you finish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using spring batch and I am inside a Reader. The transaction should be open too isn't it ? Maybe in this situation the session is not automatically open. When I look at the code of JpaPagingItemReader I can see that the EntityManager life cycle is handle is the reader.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Batch. It's a good practice to have all database operations use a transaction, even if read-only, because that way, at least you can get a consistent view on the database, depending on you isolation level.